# Maximum value of coefficient in Multinomial Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find the maximum value of coefficient in the expansion of $(x+y+z+w)^{25}$.

Basically what the question is saying is that all term will be of type $k x^{r_1}y^{r_2}z^{r_3}w^{r_4}$ so what can be maximum value of $k$.

Well in binomial expansion, middle binomial coefficients are greatest but how to expand that thought here?

I wrote it as $(a+b)^{25}$, in this expansion the term having greatest coefficient will be $C(25,13) (x+y)^{12}(z+w)^{13}$ and then take maximum binomial coefficient of $(x+y)^{12}(z+w)^{13}$ to get answer as $C(25,13) \times C(12,6) \times C(13,7)$ but I am not sure it is correct. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observation that in binomial coefficients, the central ones are largest is the key.  Let's conjecture that the same holds here: the multinomial coefficient will be largest when the difference between any two of the $r_i$ is at most $1$.  To prove this, suppose for example $r_1-r_2\geq2.$  Show that you get a larger coefficient if you replace $r_1$ by $r_1+1$ and $r_2$ by $r_2-1,$ leaving $r_3,r_4$ unchanged.  This follows  at once from your observation about the binomial coefficients.

Comment: So that means greatest coefficient is $\frac{25!}{6! 6!6! 7!}$?

Comment: @Mathematics Yes, that's right.  In general if we have $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k)^n,$ write $n=qk+r, 0\leq r<k$.  Then we we get the largest multinomial coefficients when $r$ of the $r_i$ equal $q+1$ and the other $r_i$ all equal $q.$

Comment: Did you mean replace r1 by r1-1 and r2 by r2+1? Since that makes their difference less.